# SwiperJS ReactTS Triple Slider

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I bought the pro version of swiperJS to get the Triple Slider (this thing : https://triple-slider.uiinitiative.com/)

But it's vanilla JS and I need it in ReactTS, so I need help to pass it into ReactTS, if someone know how to find this ressource, It will be very nice !

Thanks by advance !